# Calculate float with percentages of time and money

Tags: c#, math

I want to make a building process of structures in my game. The process only goes on if the percentage of time (`timer/neededTime*100`) is smaller than the percentage of money(`player.money/neededMoney*100`). Every frame, a specific amount of money, should be reduced from the `player.money`, so that the end of the whole process the `money.player = money.player - neededMoney`. I don't know how to calculate the float that is reduced from the money every frame.

Comment: Do you use float to represent money? I hope you don't. Use decimal type for financial calculations.

Comment: OTOH, in a make believe world, using decimal or float for financial calculations will only have make believe consequences.

Comment: I use int for money. I would add the float until it's 1 and after this reduce 1 money

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to subtract a part of the `neededMoney` per `neededTime` unit?

Per `neededTime` unit, which I assume is an non-negative non-zero integer value, you need to subtract `neededMoney/neededTime`.

Per frame, the code would look like something like this. Assuming `framesPerSecond` is a constant and `neededTime` is in seconds.

```
var secondsPerFrame = 1/(float)framesPerSecond;
var moneyPerSecond = neededMoney/(float)neededTime;
var moneyPerFrame = moneyPerSecond * secondsPerFrame;
//The above can be rewritten as:
//var moneyPerFrame = neededMoney/(float)neededTime/(float)framesPerSecond);

if (player.money >= moneyPerFrame)
{
    player.money -= moneyPerFrame;
}
```

**Update to support changing frame rate**

I wrote a class that should be able to deal with changing frame rates and insufficiently available funds. At each frame (or whenever appropriate), call the `GetValueToSubtract()` method.

```
public class BuildingExpenseCalculator
{
    private readonly IAccount _account;
    private readonly float _moneyNeeded;
    private readonly float _spendingRate;

    private float _moneyNeededRemaining;
    private DateTime _lastSubtract;

    public BuildingExpenseCalculator(IAccount account, float moneyNeeded, TimeSpan timeNeeded)
    {
        _account = account;
        _moneyNeeded = moneyNeeded;

        _spendingRate = moneyNeeded/(float) timeNeeded.TotalSeconds;
    }

    public void StartCalculation()
    {
        _lastSubtract = DateTime.Now;
        _moneyNeededRemaining = _moneyNeeded;
    }

    public float GetValueToSubtract()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var timePassedSinceLastSubtract = now - _lastSubtract;
        var moneyToSubtractSinceLast = (float)(_spendingRate*timePassedSinceLastSubtract.TotalSeconds);

        // Ensure we do not exceed the remaining money that is needed.
        moneyToSubtractSinceLast = Math.Min(moneyToSubtractSinceLast, _moneyNeededRemaining);

        // Ensure we do not spent more money than is available in the account.
        moneyToSubtractSinceLast = Math.Min(moneyToSubtractSinceLast, _account.AvailableMoney);

        // Update for next iteration.
        _moneyNeededRemaining -= moneyToSubtractSinceLast;
        _lastSubtract = now;

        return moneyToSubtractSinceLast;
    }
}

public interface IAccount
{
    float AvailableMoney { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: That won't sum up to the total amount in general

Comment: Sorry. Corrected my answer.

Comment: OK, but we're still in trouble. If the neededTime is not a power two, the quantity 'subtract' is slightly off, summing it a bunch of times does not necessarily work out. You can fight this effect by compensating, for example [like this](http://ideone.com/exhDZ0) (but in the real game it may be trickier to keep track of necessary quantities..)

Comment: Mhh doesn't work for me. Maybe the calculation is right, but because the framerate can differ it substracts more or less than it should. Is there a way to include the framerate to this? Maybe I can post the whole code for this

Comment: Excellent. :) Could you please approve my answer?